# Why is there only Ask Ubuntu but no Ask CentOS?

Tags: discussion, askubuntu

I know, I know, Ubuntu is easier for beginners and more popular, but why does Stack Exchange have an Ask Ubuntu site but not Ask CentOS? Although CentOS is not so popular, it's still the top choice (for some things the No.1) for using as a web server, and also because of its unpopularity there are many questions that can't be solved.

As both are Linux and one is best for normal usage and one is best for server usage, why do we have Ask Ubuntu but not Ask CentOS? Should we only ask questions at UNIX & Linux?

Comment: Have you heard about [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @Andrew Young, you can propose this site in [Area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) if you feel that it will attract a large audience. Here is their [FAQ](https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) on starting new proposals.

Comment: CentOS the top choice ? for shared hosting probably for control panel compatibility. That doesn't mean one is better than the other, you're starting on a false premise here and mostly looking to only one side of a 20+ sided die.

Answer (score 13):

Ubuntu is a special case here. So special that Robert even [wrote a blog post explicitly about this situation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/14/unix-and-ubuntu-why-both/) back in the day. I'm not going to repeat all the details of the blog here. I'm just going to reiterate that this is not something we normally do for technologies, and it's very unlikely we'd ever create a separate CentOS site in the present day.

Comment: What about [elementaryos.se], is that also a special case?

Comment: @CrazyIvan As it turns out, yes there was a bit of special-casing there, because many elementary OS users/developers do not identify with the rest of the Linux community. It didn't make sense to try and force them into a community where they weren't already participating (Unix & Linux SE, where there are [relatively few elementary OS questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-os)). That situation cannot be said of CentOS, which is very much a part of the rest of the Linux community.

Answer (score 5):

Note: The answer below shows the general process for creating a new site on the Stack Exchange Network. However this is a special case as noted by animuson in the answer above there will not be an Area51 proposal accepted for this.

This site can be proposed in [Area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) which is the site where new sites are proposed for the network.

The [FAQ](https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) on proposing a site is worth a read as it guide you through the process as well as describing what sites, should and more importantly shouldn't be.

Your site comes under the technology category so click the link below to get started.

https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/create?category=technology

P.S You will need to create an account, you can do this with your SE account as well as confirming your email as you need 50 rep to create proposals and confirming your email gives you 50 rep.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest users going to Area 51 for this. It's not going to result in anything but a closed-as-duplicate proposal.

Comment: @animuson I have editied my post, if theres anything else I need to clarify please let me know